# Merge [appstore-approval] and [appstore-approval-process] tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are two tags which are related to AppStore apps approval/rejection process.

- [appstore-approval](/questions/tagged/appstore-approval)
- [appstore-approval-process](/questions/tagged/appstore-approval-process)

First of all, most of the questions in these two tags aren't really good fit for StackOverflow, because they are more related to Apple guidelines (legal stuff) vs specific technical questions.

Secondly. There is no need for two tags (they are essentially the same). Please, can somebody merge them?

Comment: *"This tag is often used to identify questions which are off topic on StackOverflow. If this tag is appropriate for your question, please do not ask it."* - Nice tag wiki excerpt. :)

Comment: 2@animuson: yeah :)

Comment: Seconded. :-) So many possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Given that a question which *should* have either of these tags applied is all but certain to [be off-topic on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175701) (as you've noted), I'm not sure I see the point of *merging* them. The questions should be closed, and the tags removed and allowed to disappear.

I've just gone through a dozen or so questions in [appstore-approval](/questions/tagged/appstore-approval) and have found that many of them have real technical issues at heart, even if the question was prompted by App Store concerns. Questions in that class can be edited for clarity and, as above, have the tag removed.